# Retrieve Hotmail password with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook, passwords, hotmail

I have a Hotmail account that I have used since the 1990s.  Recently I forgot my password after being asked to change it.  Google Chrome still logs in to my Hotmail account automatically on my laptop, but not on other computers.  In the past if I forgot my password I had a text message sent to my cell phone.  However, I also lost that cell phone.

The only other option Hotmail offers me is to fill in a questionnaire with detailed information about recent messages and folders I have created.  However, no matter how much information I provide, the automated response refuses to provide the password.

Recently I thought maybe Google Chrome would reveal the passwords it saves and would tell me what my Hotmail password is.  However, when I go to: chrome://settings/passwords
my Hotmail account is not listed (although various other passwords for various other sites are listed).

Is there some way I can retrieve my Hotmail password from Google Chrome?

Alternatively, is there some way I can obtain my Hotmail password from Microsoft by speaking to a live person?

I can read every email sent and received, create folders, provide old passwords, and answer security questions.  But none of that is good enough.  I can even provide the phone number to which texts used to be sent before I lost the cell phone.  However, I cannot change the password without knowing what the current password is.

Thank you for any advice.  I do not wish to lose the Hotmail account given that I have used it since perhaps 1998.

Comment: Why don't you just do a "Can't access your account". Microsoft will send your details for resetting your password. Since you can access the account this shouldn't take to long to do. All they need from you is your email and fill out a captcha box.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams Perhaps I did not explain clearly that Microsoft asks me to fill in a questionnaire.  I provide very detailed and specific information but the automated reply refuses to provide the password.

Comment: So you put your email address in the login page, leave the password blank, click "can't access my account" and it gives you a big questionnaire?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I am already logged in.  I go to account settings.  That takes me to a log-in page with my address filled in but with the password blank.  I click on 'cannot access your account'.  The next option is to provide a cell phone number.  One or two options later it asks me to fill in a questionnaire.

Comment: Using a different browser do a password reset and use the email option rather than phone. Put down the email you are trying to access as the ID and see if they will send you a reset code that way. EDIT: I just tried this and it works fine. Easy way to get a reset code.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I do not see how that suggestion differs from what I have already described doing other than using a different browser would take me directly to the log-in page instead of accessing the log-in page through account settings from within the account.

Comment: Because something to do with the method of getting the password is prompting for a whole questionnaire needing to be filled out. This is not the case when requesting a security code through email. Since you can access the account you will be alerted to a new security code regardless of the email you use. You can then use the code to reset your password.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams What you are describing does not work for me and is not consistent with what I see.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.engadget.com/2013/08/07/chrome-saved-passwords/ its an old hack may be it is fixed now. cheers!!

Comment: Is that not the same page as the one at the link I provided in my post?  chrome://settings/passwords

Comment: hmmm, looks like a bug in chrome, https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xfHSgU565Wg    the same site has some workarounds.

Comment: Did you try using [ChromePass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html)?

Comment: @and31415 Have you used it successfully?  I attempted to download and run it but anti-virus blocked it.  The laptop is a university computer and the university OIT office refuses to assist in installing the software or recovering the password.  The only advice they have offered is to try calling my old cell phone number and hope whoever answers might be willing to help by relaying a text from Hotmail.

Comment: Yes, assuming the password is actually stored. The program itself has a valid digital signature, but since it deals with Chrome passwords some antivirus programs might warn you about it being a Potentially Unwanted Program (PUP), a hack tool, a riskware, or something along those lines. If the antivirus won't let unblock it or set an exception, you might as well start Windows in Safe Mode, and try running it from there.

Answer (score 2):

If your Google Chrome was set to **remember my password** & if you are authentic local account user.

You can retrieve your passwords following the instructions below:

1. Go to chrome://settings & scroll down to the bottom
2. Click on **Show Advanced Settings**

[image]

3. Scroll down to **Passwords & forms** section & click on **Manage Passwords**

[image]

4. Search for the site in **Manage Password** list & click on **Show**
5. **Authenticate using your computer password** when asked
6. Yo should see the password after successful authentication
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. I hope this information helps.

"The customer service number for Hotmail is 866-672-4551 or 800-642-7676. A customer service representative is available between 8 a.m. and 1 p.m. from Monday through Friday – or between 8 a.m. and 8 p.m. on Saturday or Sunday."

You can try call the number above, but the only way to retrieve the account is by online and filling in information.

Afterwards I went to support.microsoft.com to talk to the person directly online, and fortunately received the web link for the form which leads to directly to the technicians.

Right now I am just filling in. 
"I want to set proper expectation that the success of this will depend on the information that you will enter."

Comment: So, what you're saying is that the methods already tried by the user are the only available methods. Calling will not work because you still have to fill out the form they have already filled out?

Answer (score 0):

Ok give this a try.

Go to your login screen on Chrome where it shows the email and hidden password. Right click the password box and click "Inspect Element". On the highlighted line of code double click and change type="password" to type="text" and press enter.

Should show you the password

Comment: I see no password displayed when I do this.

Comment: Lets test something out here then. Load Chrome > Go to hotmail.com > type "someemail" and "somepassword" into the relevant login boxes. Follow the above steps. Does is change the hidden password to a revealed password (in the password box)?

Comment: Yes, that reveals "somepassword" but I do not see how this will help since it is only revealing what I type into it.  The correct password is not present on the log-in screen hidden by a string of asterisks so it does not seem to be waiting for me to reveal it with the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get access to your account through the questionnaire your best bet is to call [support](http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/), maybe they can help you further.

When you have full control of your account again make sure to change your account settings and add a current phonenumber AND secondairy e-mail address, you might also want to think about password management software like [keepass](http://keepass.info). (I know this doens't help you right now but I've learned to use it the hard way and never lost a password again.)

Comment: I see no phone number at the link you provided or at other pages related to Outlook connected to that link.

Comment: It's a localized page, I get the Dutch page and that does have a number, try searching for any kind of microsoft support, once you have a person on the line they can connect you through to the right department.

Answer (score 0):

I had a phone number associated with the account.  However, as explained in the original post, I lost that cell phone.

Fortunately, that phone number was out of service this month.  I had to purchase another cell phone and have that old phone number assigned to the new phone.  Then I was able to have a security code sent to that new phone and I created a new Hotmail password.

Answer (score 0):

Since google chrome is making auto login for the hotmail account eventhough you are unable to find the password for it.

Google chrome would store the password and history information in the following location for default profile C:\Users\\Appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ so there is tool called Gmail Password Dump which would export the password.

You can download the tool Gmail Password Dump.It would get installed in the location C:\Program Files (x86)\SecurityXploded\ChromePasswordDump.To use the tool you need to  use the command prompt to navigate the location and then try to run the command ChromePasswordDump.exe.

If the profile is in different location,you can execute the command

C:\Program Files (x86)\SecurityXploded\ChromePasswordDump>ChromePasswordDump.exe
 -f "C:\Users\vembu\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"