# Retrieve password from auto login page

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords, login

I realize there are several similar posts but I believe this one is unique.

I usually sign into a a wireless network that does not have WEP. There is no password listed in the properties.

However, when logged on, the first webpage that comes up is the network webpage for the internet provider, and I must login there. I have forgotten this password.  Is there any way to retrieve it?  When I login now it automatically enters the password and I dont even see it, but when logging in from a new computer it brings me to the password page.

If anyone can help it that would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Which operating system? Which browser?

Comment: What exactly have you tried already and what were the results?  What makes you think yours in "unique" exactly?

Comment: "Is there any way to retrieve it?" - No;  You can determine what the password is if you brute force attack it, but that would cause you problems with your providers, just reset the account's password.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your browser is storing the pw for you.

Chrome(the answer from @the-it-guy-you-dont-like): 
[Retrieve Hotmail password with Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/712124/retrieve-hotmail-password-with-google-chrome)

Firefox - this probably has already been given, but my (quick) search didn't turn it up - Preferences, Security, Saved Passwords.

No IE or Safari on this machine, but Google will fix that for you.